# Would an NAS with cheap drives serve files faster than a PC with high-performance drives?

Tags: hard-drive, home-networking, nas, file-sharing

First, a little background. We have two computers, which we built. We also have two phones and a tablet, all running Android, as well as a PS3. Currently, one of the computers acts as a file server for the other devices, in addition to being my rig for gaming and game development. It has the following specifications:

- ASUS P6X58D Premium
- Intel Core i7 920
- 12 GB (2 GB x 6) DDR3 (PC3-12800 @ 8-8-8-24)
- nVidia GTX 670
- Hard Drives:

  - 2 TB Western Digital Black
  - 1 TB Samsung Spinpoint F1
  - 3 TB Western Digital SE (for backup)

It currently shares documents, multimedia, portable programs, downloads, and other stuff. This share is VERY BIG, and it's competing for space with my games and game development environment. In particular, the movie library, which consists of almost nothing but Blu-Ray quality videos @ 1080p, is slowly approaching the 1 TB mark. Additionally, accessing these files via LAN is often quite slow, which I assume is due to the fact that the PC is already too busy doing its own stuff. So, we've thought about building an NAS, but this decision hinges on one very important issue. We can add several "green" hard drives for massive storage (incl. backup) at a relatively low price. Will the inherent speed benefits of an NAS outweigh the lack of high-performance hard drives like the WD Black?

```
Note: I'm too geeky to buy pre-built computers.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'll soon be building a Linux server for my PHP stuff. If we decide against an NAS, then we'll build a cheap server that will read files from my main PC as needed. Otherwise, we'll build a bigger server that will also act as an NAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your NAS is a separate system you can add the hardware and tweak it better for your needs - if it isn't fast enough, you can make it so.

The number one thing that will affect file server speed is amount of RAM you put in the system, unless you are doing continuous simultaneous reading/writing.  So building your own box and putting a lot of RAM in it will provide this benefit regardless of the drives you select.

If you are playing games, you are likely playing online games which take some bandwidth away from your file serving.

One thing you can do easily in a NAS is junction two drives together in a RAID-0 or "striped" type set up which could increase performance at the cost of decreasing your effective MTBF.

Comment: Thank you. It's easy to forgot how much difference RAM can make, especially considering that it's one of the cheapest and easy-to-upgrade components in a computer.